# How to React component extend all passed properties?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I creating a `React` like following component:

```
class UploadInput extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <input type="file" {}/>
        );
    }
}
```

When I using:

```
<UploadInput anyProp="value" />
```

How to can I make for `UploadInput` extends all I passing properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly what you want is when you do this:

```
<UploadInput type="text" name="some name" value="some value" ... />
```

you need `input` inside `UploadInput` to be rendered like this:

```
<input type="text" name="some name" value="some value" ... />
```

**Solution:** You can use [JSX Spread operator](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes) for that:

```
<input {...this.props} />
```

Whatever props you are passing to `UploadInput` component will be passed down to `input` as well.

Comment: Very thank you! But if has children, React know how to handle this itself?